# How to debug iOS framework dyld "lazy symbol binding failed" crashes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm building an iPad app for iOS 10.2 using Xcode 8.2.1 on OS X 10.11.6, and when I attempt to invoke code that makes use of a specific dependency built by [Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage), the app crashes and appears to indicate that the framework binary isn't in memory as expected:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: __TFC12ObjectMapper6MapperCfT7contextGSqPS_10MapContext___GS0_x_
  Referenced from: /Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/<UUID>/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/<UUID>/AppName.app/Frameworks/AlamofireObjectMapper.framework/AlamofireObjectMapper
  Expected in: /Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/<UUID>/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/<UUID>/AppName.app/Frameworks/ObjectMapper.framework/ObjectMapper

dyld: Symbol not found: __TFC12ObjectMapper6MapperCfT7contextGSqPS_10MapContext___GS0_x_
  Referenced from: /Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/<UUID>/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/<UUID>/AppName.app/Frameworks/AlamofireObjectMapper.framework/AlamofireObjectMapper
  Expected in: /Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/<UUID>/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/<UUID>/AppName.app/Frameworks/ObjectMapper.framework/ObjectMapper
```

I'm using [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) to make a HTTPS call, and [AlamofireObjectMapper](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper) (and, by extension, [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper/)) to parse the response JSON. It has worked well for many prior runs of this app/project, and seemingly spontaneously started crashing.

What's bizarre is that the Alamofire calls *do* make the request and receive the response, but the crash happens when parsing the response (whose format or data has not changed). So, clearly, including Carthage-built frameworks is working for some dependencies, but not others. I'm specifying `==` in my `Cartfile` as well as using `Cartfile.resolved` to pin exact versions for all dependencies.

### What I've Tried

- Roll code back to a known-good commit to verify that it's not a newly-introduced code change at fault
- Quit and re-launch Xcode
- Quit and re-launch iOS Simulator
- Clean Xcode "Derived Data" folder
- Restart the machine
- Trashed and re-built Carthage dependencies (`carthage update --platform iOS`)
- Verified that `ObjectMapper.framework` is included in the target's *Link Binary With Libraries* build phase along with other Carthage-built frameworks:
  [image: Link Binary With Libraries Build Phase]
- Verified the path `$(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/ObjectMapper.framework` is included in the Input Files for the *Run Script* build phase for running `/usr/local/bin/carthage copy-frameworks`, alongside other nearly identical (and working) framework paths:
  [image: Copy Frameworks Run Script Build Phase]
- Clean product and re-build with Xcode
- Verified that the ObjectMapper framework binary is present in the built app bundle in `<DerivedData>/AppName.app/Frameworks/ObjectMapper.framework/ObjectMapper`

It's beyond me why this framework is apparently being built, included, but not loaded. How can I debug this issue more deeply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered same problem. Check this issue on AlamofireObjectMappter Github.

https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper/issues/179

AlamofireObjectMapper probably does NOT support ObjectMapper latest version... fix version on 2.2.1 on carthage `github "Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper" "2.2.1"`

Comment: That was my issue, thanks!  In the interim, I was informed by others to use some dyld debugging environment variables (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2239/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010638-CH1-SUBSECTION21), as well as to inspect the ObjectMapper framework binary with `lipo -info /path/to/framework/binary` to see if there's a slice for whatever architecture is needed.